# How does the Spotify Windows desktop application authenticate the user?

Tags: facebook, authentication, desktop, spotify

I noticed that the Windows desktop Spotify application asks me for my facebook username and password in the login screen. I am wondering what happens behind the scenes.

When I change my fb password in my browser I have to use the new password in the Spotify desktop app login screen. There are even situations when the Spotify desktop application shows me a fb popup where I have to grant permissions for Spotify itself.

I know that Spotify uses an embedded Chromium browser engine to do all the heavy lifting. But isn't it against Facebooks TOS to do it that way?

I mean, does Spotify posts my username and password to the facebook login.php and intercepts the result page to get my cookie? Is there a documented way to handle a login to facebook on behalf of the user in a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are using an old and deprecated REST API method called `auth.login`:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.login/

Obviously I can't stop you using this in your own app, but given how old that API is and how fully REST API is now deprecated, it'd be a bad idea to rely upon it.

Instead, for Windows desktop apps, I believe Microsoft offers a Facebook C# SDK which will contain ideal methods for authentication. I'm more familiar with their newer methods that are offered for Metro Apps called [Web Authentication Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750287.aspx).

These pretty much just load a web frame inside the app, get the user to login to Facebook, then show the Permission Dialog (if required). From there, the app can store the UID of the user and presumably a long-lived access_token that they received upon auth. This way, they only need to ask the user to login again once every 60 days.

There are [other device-based authentication methods](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/) offered by Facebook, but most are still in private testing, the only one that is currently recommend for desktop apps is stated on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) under the heading **Windows, OS X and Linux native apps** (at the bottom of the page).

**Update December 2013:** Because the Facebook Login docs have changed significantly since I wrote this answer, I'd like to point out a couple of new additions:

- [Manually Building a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) details the steps that desktop apps can take to login users. What is new here is that Windows 8 apps can now use their deep-linking ID in the redirect_uri of the Login dialog, meaning it'll multitask back to their app from a Login Dialog when completed or cancelled. This is an improvement from the previous WebView setup, because a User's default browser will likely have them logged into Facebook already.
- [Login for Windows Phone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone/) is the special guide for Windows Phone 8 apps to use.

Comment: Thanks! Actually we have an embedded Chromium in our desktop app, too. However, if i present the user a "login with facebook" button within our desktop app the user experience is somewhat odd:

Comment: Because there is no cookie at the beginning the user is redirected to full featured the fb login screen. There he can not only login, but register and eventually start surfing the web. So the login experience is severely broken. Any thoughts how to let users login & authenticate a desktop App without such a broken experience?